# Switch statement using numeric patterns

Tags: python, switch-statement, pattern-matching, bit-manipulation

I'm attempting to create a switch statement for a given value. The value is a 16-bit unsigned number, and I want to jump to the appropriate pattern. Each pattern is a hexadecimal string, but an underscore denotes a wildcard. For example, (0x1234 matches '1234' and '12_4' but not '56_8'). While I'm only posting a subset of these patterns, assume they cover the entire range of 0x0000-0xFFFF.

```py
patterns = {
    '15__': foo,
    '2__0': bar,
    '8__0': baz,
    ...
}

...

def run(self, x: int) -> None:

    # x to string (0x567f -> "567F")
    x_str = str(hex(opcode))[2:].zfill(4).upper()

    # Search for the matching pattern and execute the associated method
    for pattern, instruction in patterns.items():
        if all([x_str[i] == pattern[i] for i in range(len(pattern)) if pattern[i] != '_'):
            instruction(x)
            break
```

Now, this works. However, it is incredibly slow, and defeats the purpose of using a dictionary since it just iterates through it. Also, since it has to convert x to a string (with formatting) then check that string against the pattern string, the whole thing is a giant bottleneck. I'm looking for a way to, preferably, get it closer to an actual lookup table, bonus points if we don't need to convert x to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch statement of this type *is* an iterative process, not a jump table.  In the general case you present, the way to avoid iteration is to generate the graph of partial indexing decisions, based on the specific arrangement of common digits (hexits) and wild cards in your table.

Instead, try simply speeding up your matching.  I suggest that you take a mask-and-match approach to your table keys.  Code the "don't-care" (wild-card) positions separately, and keep the key as a tuple of match and mask values.  Your examples would be

```
patterns = {
    (0x1500, 0xFF00): foo,
    (0x2000, 0xF00F): bar,
    (0x8000, 0xF00F): baz,
    ...
}
```

To check a particular key against your candidate `cand`, you look for bit equality, but mask off any mismatches in the wild-card positions:

```
cand ^ match       # bit inequality; mismatch is 1
result & mask      # force don't-care bits to 0
```

So that you can check

```
if (cand ^ match) & mask:
    continue      # Something doesn't match
else:
    return value from dict
```

Your dict format is

```
(match, mask): value
```

Can you handle the logic for iteration and return value?